# JQuery get the first td by clicking a button on the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might be a simple question, however I tried everything and it didn't work.

I would like to click a button that is on the 3rd td to get the the text of the first td. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Btton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="b" value="alert" onclick="alert1();" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As I mentioned I tried different things, for example

```
function alert1() {
    alert($(this).closest("tr").first().text());
}
```

However, it alerts with an empty box. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: $(this).closest("tr").first() selects the first TR in a set of TR.. you could instead do $(this).closest("tr").find("td").first().text()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [.find](https://api.jquery.com/find/), and pass the element that you clicked to the function.

```js
function alert1(elm) {
    alert($(elm).closest("tr").find("td:first-child").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Btton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="b" value="alert" onclick="alert1(this);" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or you could use an [event listener](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery

```js
$("#b").on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).closest("tr").find("td:first-child").text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Btton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="b" value="alert" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass button reference using `this` keyword. And also use `$(elm).closest("tr").find("td").first()` to select first `td`. 
You can do it like following

```js
function alert1(elm) {
    alert($(elm).closest("tr").find("td").first().text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Btton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="b" value="alert" onclick="alert1(this);" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first issue is that you're attaching the event handler using `onclick`. This means that the `this` scope will actually be the window, not the clicked element. To fix this you can use jQuery to attach the event handler, seen as you're using it already.

You can then get the `closest('tr')`, and then `find()` for the first `td`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#b').click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find('td:first').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Btton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="b" value="alert" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the reference of the `<button>` in `alert1()` like this `alert1(this)`. So that you can use the reference of this button inside `alert1()`.

```js
function alert1(_this) {
    alert($(_this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Btton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="b" value="alert" onclick="alert1(this);" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or you can also add the `click` listner to the `<button>` from the `JQuery` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#b').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Btton</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tom</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="b" value="alert" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

You don't need to use the `onclick` attribute on the HTML. Also if you have lots of button like this then use a `class` selector instead of `id` selector which i have used now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 function alert1() {
   alert($(this).closest("tr:first-child").text());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have nested the button inside the

```
<td>
```

tags, so the

```
<td>
```

is its parent.

You can therefore do something like:

```
$("#b").on('click', function(){
    var first = $( this ).parent().siblings().first();
    console.log(first.text()); //Tom
});
```